# Is it possible to open two files simultaneously in Multisim?

Tags: multisim

It seems that Multisim provides useful feature of
File trees:
[image: file tree]

And design file tabs:
[image: tabs]

However, I was never able to find the way to use them. Is it possible to open different files at the same time for multisim. If so, could I ask for some tutorials? I tried to find some on the internet. But with no luck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is nothing difficult about it, you can use the open menu to open several files (of click new to design a new one) and they will show each to a separate tab. By clicking one of the tabs you can go from one project to the other. Also the tree will show a branch for each of the tabs, so an alternative way to change between tabs is to click on the tree branches.

Comment: @alexan_e , thanks for your reply. However, that does not seem to be the case for me. Whenever I click new or open, the current file/project will be closed.. Is it because of my version, which is version for Analog Device? Or because of some sort of settings for the software?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting that behaviour. I have used versions NI 10 to 13 and they all had the behaviour I have described. Maybe it's a limitation of the version you have, although I'm not sure of the point of preventing a user to open multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

To open multiple files in Multisim you just have to use the open menu. To switch between the files you should see tabs with the opened file's names in the bottom left hand corner of your screen. If you're talking about having the two files opened and active at the same time you can press the Restore Down/Maximize button to make the file not take up the full work space. From there you can adjust the windows sizes' to how you see fit.